# Images are not getting loaded on the PDF when generated from HTML until I use webview

Tags: html, ios, iphone, swift, pdf-generation

I want to make PDF from Html which contains images as well as content and the data is fully dynamic and number of images are also dynamic. When I generate the PDF via HTML then only text content is loaded in the PDF and when I use UIWebview and call its delegate methot webViewDidFinishLoad() and in this delgate method when i Call a method to convert the html to PDF then Images are getting loaded. Can anyone tell why this problem happening with me.